# Listbox is being set to Null somehow in excel-vba user form

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

Context: I am coding a user form which will have some filters to run a procedure and fill a worksheet with the return value.

I am having trouble with one of my filters. I was able to reproduce my issue in a reduced version. This filter should load data into a listbox based on the selected combobox option:

[image]

I didn't rename anything, the components are: `UserForm1`, `ListBox1` and `ComboBox1`.

My *broken* code (commented):

```
Option Explicit

'sub that fill data in the list box columns
Sub loadList(list As ListBox, id As Integer)
    list.Clear
    If (id > 0) Then
        list.AddItem
        list.Column(0, 0) = "Item 1"
        list.AddItem
        list.Column(0, 1) = "Item 2"
    End If
End Sub

'event that will trigger the loadList sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim id As Integer
    id = ComboBox1.ListIndex

    loadList ListBox1, id
End Sub

'the combo options is auto initialized
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem
    ComboBox1.Column(0, 0) = "Option 1"
    ComboBox1.AddItem
    ComboBox1.Column(0, 1) = "Option 2"
End Sub
```

When I set a brekpoint I can see the problem. The `ListBox1` is being set to `Null`, but I don't know how to work around it:

[image]

The error says:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

But it is obvious because the `ListBox1` is being set to `Null` somehow.

Have anyone experienced this behaviour before? How to work around it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fadi. Nothing changed, if I set the breakpoint one line above, the `ListBox1` is still `Null`, I think the error is happening before the `Sub loadList` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange as it looks, there are two classes named `ListBox` from different libraries, and VBA confuses them (the same applies to all controls actually). It depends on whether you are using the `MSForms` controls or the `ActiveX` controls.

In your case, you should disambiguate with `MSForms.ListBox` which is the actual type of your listbox.

```
Sub loadList(list As MSForms.ListBox, id As Integer)
'                    ^^^^^^^
```

To avoid such doubts, you can also use `list As Object`, (would make your sub handle both types as long as you use only the common methods).

[image]

Comment: Man, you are a ninja! I would never find it.. Really thanks :)